# Installing Ubuntu across multiple hard drives

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I am building a new PC and I want to only have Ubuntu on it.

It has two hard drives, one being a 180 GB SSD drive and the other a 2 TB  HDD. I want to use this system mainly for work (software developement for embedded systems, android and web development) and also for entertainment.

My question is, what would be the ideal distributing of Linux folders for example `/home` `/etc` `/temp` in this situation? With the focus of getting the maximum out of the SSD drive so booting up and routine works be fast.please let me know what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different suggestion. Not necessarily better. Each user has to decide how he will use system.

I prefer to have / (root) on SSD but not a separate /boot or any other system partitions. And I leave /home inside root so the user settings are also on the faster drive. But then create data partition(s) on rotating drive for all data and link data back to /home so it looks like it all is in /home.

My 64GB SSD has two / installs, one 12.04, and 14.04 each half of SSD, I will probably overwrite 12.04 when 16.04 is released. I also keep all data on hard drive but also have test installs (at least one reasonably current) so hard drive could be booted in an emergency if issues with SSD. Each test install is 20 or 25GB and I link in the data partitions, so everything is otherwise configured the same.

Answer (score 1):

For quick booting, you would want it to boot from the SSD.

Usually /boot is 300 to 500MB, put this on the SSD at the **beginning**. I normally suggest / (root) of 20 or 25GB also on the SSD (**After** the /boot). Now you can add /home or data partition(s) onto the 2TB drive.

Hope this helps